# Sorting time always different from first sort

Tags: java, sorting, time-complexity

I wrote couple sorting algorithm. I want to compare their sorting times, at least nearly. But after first loop all sorting times decreasing except StoogeSort. I think something optimizating at background but which measure should I consider? First one or the others? And why is this happening?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomNumber rn = new RandomNumber();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter the input size.");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] experimentalArray = rn.experimentalArrayGenerator(n);



        Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
        StoogeSort ss = new StoogeSort(experimentalArray.clone());
        System.out.println("StoogeSort : " + sw1.elapsedTime() + " µs");

        Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
        RadixSort rs = new RadixSort(experimentalArray.clone());
        System.out.println("RadixSort : " + sw2.elapsedTime() + " µs");

        Stopwatch sw3 = new Stopwatch();
        ShakerSort shs = new ShakerSort(experimentalArray.clone());
        System.out.println("ShakerSort : " + sw3.elapsedTime() + " µs");

        Stopwatch sw4 = new Stopwatch();
        MaximumSubarray ms = new MaximumSubarray();
        int a = ms.maxSubArraySum(experimentalArray.clone());
        System.out.println("MaximumSubarray : " + sw4.elapsedTime() + " µs");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Output after 4 loop:

[image]

Comment: Sorting random number arrays will almost never take the same amount of time.

Comment: But this is weird. Just the first one different from others.

Comment: Take for example the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. How many itterations would an algorithm take to sort it? Then consider the array [10,5,3,7,2,8,1,9,6,4]. Would it take the same amount of time?

Comment: Aside from anything else, the first execution path will involve different JITting, quite possibly different GC experiences etc.

Answer (score 1):

Microbenchmarking is a complicated matter as many factors influence the execution time (e.g. just-in-time compilation and garbage collection as noted by Jon Skeet in the comments).

You should read [this document](http://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/papers/benchmarking.pdf) by Peter Sestoft if you want to gain an understanding of how you should approach microbenchmarking.

Quoting the abstract of the document here, as the document is an external resource:

> Sometimes one wants to measure the speed of software, for instance, to
>   measure whether a new way to solve a problem is faster than the old
>   one. Making such time measurements and microbenchmarks requires
>   considerable care, especially on managed platforms like the Java
>   Virtual Machine and Microsoft’s Common Language Infrastructure (.NET),
>   or else the results may be arbitrary and misleading.
>
> Here we give some
>   advice on running microbenchmarks, in particular for managed
>   platforms. Most examples are in Java but the advice applies to any
>   language executed on a managed platform, including Scala, C# and F#.
>   This version uses Java functional interfaces and requires Java 8.